# What component is this (name or #)?

Tags: pcb, identification

Does anyone know the name/part # of this component? I believe the logo on the component is from Matsushita Electronics (before they became Panasonic around 2008). The strange part is that the component is on a PCB from a very new device. I tried the typical search but couldn't find anything. It's right beside a ADS1299 (AFE) and a ISO7721 (Digital Isolator).

My initial guess was that it was a LNA but it's only 4 channels... Any insight is helpful :)

[image]

Comment: Can you share the device name, I would try to find in FCCI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a Panasonic AQY212S part but I can't find the model like your picture.
[image]